# How can I create a stylesheet external link using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

A link with "rel", "href" and "type", just like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Just to prove that I've tried, here's my failed attempt:

```
def add_css(self, *links):
    if links:
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup("<link>")
        for link in links:
            new_soup.attrs["rel"] = "stylesheet"
            new_soup.attrs["href"] = link
            new_soup.attrs["type"] = "text/css"
        self.soup.head.insert(0, new_soup)
        self.update_document()
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head><html><head><link/></head></html>
<title></title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there's an empty link tag there. I've tried like this, by the way:

```
webpage.add_css("css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we an create directly like:

```
>>> new_soup = BeautifulSoup('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">')
>>> new_soup
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
>>> type(new_soup)
<class 'BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup'>
>>>
```

Related to code, there are many `links`, so create `link tag` statement need to be inside the `for` loop

```
    for link in links:
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup('<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s" type="text/css">'%link)
        self.soup.head.insert(0, new_soup)
    self.update_document()
```

**[Edit 2]**
Insert `link` tag into html by BeautifulSoup:

**Demo**:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# Parser content by BeautifulSoup.
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><head></head><body></body></html>")
>>> soup
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
# Create New tag.
>>> new_tag = BeautifulSoup('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>')
>>> new_tag
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
# Insert created New tag into head tag i.e. first child of head tag.
>>> soup.head.insert(0,new_tag)
>>> soup
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /></head><body></body></html>
>>> new_tag = BeautifulSoup('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom1.css"/>')
>>> new_tag
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom1.css" />
>>> soup.head.insert(0,new_tag)
>>> soup
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom1.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /></head><body></body></html>
>>>
```

---

**[Edit 3]**

**I think you are imported `BeautifulSoup` from the `bs4` module.**

`BeautifulSoup` is class and which take html content as argument.

**Create New Tag:**

Use `new_tag` method of `BeautifulSoup` class to create new tag.

Use `attrs` property of `new_tag` to add `class`, `href` attributes and its values.

**Demo**:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><head></head><body></body></html>")
>>> soup
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
>>> new_link =  soup.new_tag("link")
>>> new_link
<link/>
>>> new_link.attrs["href"] = "custom1.css"
>>> new_link
<link href="custom1.css"/>
>>> soup.head.insert(0, new_link)
>>> soup
<html><head><link href="custom1.css"/></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: You're right, but I had to change to `self.soup.head.insert(0, new_soup.find("link"))`, because it was inserting "html" tags as well.

Comment: @RederickDeathwill: I updated answer, can you check it is working for you?

Comment: @RederickDeathwill: Updated answer again, I think updated content is useful to you. :)